# Android several images downloaded from server are being corrupted

Tags: java, android

I'm using a function to download an image from a server to the internal memory of my android device, the function is :

```
private void downloadFile(String myurl, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count=0;

    try {

        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test library/"+name.replace(" ","")+".png");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {a=e.toString();}
}
```

I have 22 images on the server, the problem is that some images are being downloaded as corrupted files, any help please ?

Comment: Have you had a look at what is in the corrupted files?  (I'm betting that it is an error message in HTML ... or something like that ...)

Comment: show some log. connection time out may occur in there or out of memory

Comment: We never know what the extension of the image is. So don't place `.png` extension at the end of the file name. It causes the corrupted file.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH If I remove the extension the pictures won't be opened !! so of course this is not the problem